# Checkbox Using "fieldname[ ]" breaks jquery validation

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

So I have a form which needs to be validated. The rest of the form validation works but when i add the checkbox group using the php attribute [] to form the check box into an array. The checkboxes no longer work with my validation script.

```
$("form[name='violationsForm']").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden,[name='']", // do not validate form fields in invisible sections
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         $(element).attr("class","error");
         error.insertAfter(element);
     },
    rules: {
         owner_address: { required: true, minlength: 5 }
        ,owner_county: { required: true, minlength: 1 }
        ,date1: { required: true, minlength: 2 }
        ,time1: { required: true, minlength: 2 }
        ,timeframe1: { required: true, minlength: 2 }
        ,violation[]: { required: true}
    }

});
```

adding ***,violation[]: { required: true}*** Breaks the entire validation script. 
Below is my form input for ref.

```
<li>
<label><strong>Type of Violation (required):</strong></label><br />
<label>type 1 <input type="checkbox" id="violation" name="violation[]" value="1"     
 title="Please choose at least ONE violation."/></label><br />
 <label>type 2 <input type="checkbox" id="violation" name="violation[]" value="2" />  
</label><br />
<label>type 3 <input type="checkbox" id="violation" name="violation[]" value="3" />
</label><br />
<label>type 4 <input type="checkbox" id="violation" name="violation[]" value="4" />
</label><br />
<label>type 5 <input type="checkbox" id="violation" name="violation[]" value="5" />  
</label><br />
<label>Other <input type="checkbox" id="violation_0" name="violation[]" value="other" />
</label><br />
</li>
```

Since I am using php I'd prefer to keep [] attached to my input "name" value. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround it in quotes:

```
"violation[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

special characters need escaping with double backslash in jQuery selectors. When you are creating the keys for rules object, they will get used as selectors.

Top section of selectors API has all the escaping info
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/